# SQL syntax error generated by phpMyAdmin when updating field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, updating

I need to change some domain name into a table containing e-mail addresses (primary key).
I tried to extract (with a `select`) the fields that I need to update:

```sql
SELECT `Email`, CONCAT( 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Email`, '@olddomain.', 1),
    '@newdomain.', 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Email`, '@olddomain.', -1)) AS NewMail
FROM `mailaddresses` 
WHERE INSTR(`Email`,'@olddomain.')>0
```

**This works fine and gives me old and new e-mails.**
Follows an example of the returned data:

```
   EMail               NewMail
123@olddomain.com   123@newdomain.com
456@olddomain.com   456@newdomain.com
789@olddomain.com   789@newdomain.com
```

So I tried to update using the following query:

```sql
UPDATE `mailaddresses` 
    SET `Email` = CONCAT( 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Email`, '@olddomain.', 1),
        '@newdomain.', 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Email`, '@olddomain.', -1)) 
WHERE INSTR(`Email`, '@olddomain.')>0
```

But phpMyAdmin is saying that there's an SQL syntax error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1) '@newdomain.' SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Email`'@olddomain.', )) FROM
>   `mailaddresses` WHER' at line 2

**I noticed that two commas ',' are missing in the error message** so I think phpMyAdmin is doing something nasty there.

**EDIT**:
I realized that **my SQL code is fully working because I tested it on a MySQL console and it's working fine. I think I have problems with PhpMyAdmin** (I don't know what kind of problems though).

Here some data from my Xampp/PhpMyAdmin home page:

> Database server
>       Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
>       Server type: MySQL
>       Server version: 5.6.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>       Protocol version: 10
>   Web server
>       Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8
>       Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $
>       PHP extension: mysqli
>   phpMyAdmin
>       Version information: 4.3.11

I'm sure of this because I ran my SQL code from vb.net and it worked.

So my questions are:
Is there anyone who has had the same problem?
How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: it seems this field has an unique index and after such changes you are getting duplicate records. so share error details so that it can be checked.

Comment: I do not know where your syntax error comes from but it seems you are trying to re-implement the replace-Function of mysql. Maybe better use that instead: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: @OP: Why did you use `@xxxdomain` as *literals* ??? Aren't they session variables???

Comment: @OP: And it seems you have posted a different query statement that does not show the partial statement as seen in error statement ...

Comment: @RavinderReddy I posted what phpMyAdmin returns to me. '@' is a char of the mail address, but even if I cut off it, I get syntax error

Comment: @genespos: Observe error statement keenly.... Some *comma*s are missing ....

Comment: @RavinderReddy I already noted it. I wrote it into my question. But 'commas' are missing only into the error message not in my query!!!

Comment: Can you post a existing sample `email` field value and the target value?

Comment: If you think it's phpMyAdmin post its version. Have you tried running the same query on the MySQL shell? Still getting the error? Have you tried updating phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @FrancescoCasula I added version data. I tryed to run query from xampp shell and it worked

Comment: The latest version is 4.5.4.1. I suggest you try to update it. You can also try to run your query on a single PHP script file than you can run from the CLI just to see if you're getting the same error also there.

Comment: @FrancescoCasula I Updated to 4.5.4.1 and now it works. Thanks. If You'll post it as answer I'll accept

Comment: @genespos I'm glad it's solved :) The answer is posted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks from your question that you're using an outdated version of phpMyAdmin plus the very same query apparently works when ran on the MySQL console itself. I therefore suggest you update phpMyAdmin to its latest version. At the moment of writing is the [v4.5.4.1](https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.5.4.1/phpMyAdmin-4.5.4.1-all-languages.7z).

Here the [changelogs](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.5.4.1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***`REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)`***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) string function to change part of any field value...

```
UPDATE mailaddresses 
   SET email = REPLACE( email, '@olddomain.', '@newdomain' )
 WHERE INSTR( email, '@olddomain.' ) > 0
```

**Example**:

```
mysql> set @olddomain = '@google.com';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @newdomain = '@gmail.com';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @email = 'rr.arepally@google.com';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select replace( @email, @olddomain, @newdomain ) as modified_email;
+-----------------------+
| modified_email        |
+-----------------------+
| rr.arepally@gmail.com |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I don't understand what's happening: I get syntax error and again into the error message commas are missing